# array of html elements empty or not

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I have a form in which I have a field Work_Location[] which is an array. I want to check if it is empty or not. I did

```
     var ele=document.myForm.elements['Work_Location[]'];
     alert(ele.length);
    if(ele.length==0)
    {
        alert("Please enter Work_Location");
        //document.myForm.EMail.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
```

alert(ele.length) prints undefined.whereas according to me it should print number of elements in the array

HTML code

```
<form action="trainer_register.php" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" method="post"  id="my-from" onsubmit="return validate();">
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
 <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Preferred Work Location</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
<input type="text" id="loc" name="Work_Location[]" class="form-control" >
</div>
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Locations</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: posted the HTML code

Comment: `Work_Location[]` is not an array.  It's simply the name of your input element.  Do you have other inputs with the same name?

Comment: I have a button which dynamically adds elements having name Work_location

Comment: Gotcha.  Looks like @RLHawk gave you a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using document.form.elements["name"] returns an array if there are more than one fields matching the name, but just returns the element itself if there's only one element.

So if ele is defined but ele.length is not defined, then there is one result.

Try adding another  and you'll see that ele.length now returns 2.

Comment: Yes you are correct.But then how do I check whether there are 0  or more than 0 elements?

Comment: If there are 0 elements, ele will be undefined. So, to get the element count, you could do something like:

    var count = ele === undefined ? 0 : (ele.length === undefined ? 1 : ele.length);